# Migrations does not register on TypeORM on Ionic and Vue using Capacitor

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, ionic-framework, typeorm, capacitor

I am creating an Ionic5 app(with Vue3) using [capacitor-sqlite plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite). I am also trying to use TypeORM on top all this.

I can connect to the sqlite database using capacitor but for some reason the migrations does not seem to be getting registered at all and always comes out as an empty array with the following code:

```js
// App.vue

import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {CapacitorSQLite, SQLiteConnection} from "@capacitor-community/sqlite";

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    const sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);
    createConnection({
        type: 'capacitor',
        driver: sqlite,
        database: 'mydrivetime',
        synchronize: false,
        migrationsRun: false,
        logging: true,
        entities: [
            "User"
        ],
        migrations: [
            "1626771964722-UserCreate"
        ],
    }).then(async connection => {

        console.log('migrations', connection.migrations);
        console.log('isConnected', connection.isConnected);

        connection.runMigrations()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("migrations successful");
          }).catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));

    });
});
```

I get the following output for this even though I have the migration setup on the same path:

```
⚡️  [log] - migrations []
⚡️  [log] - isConnected true
⚡️  [log] - migrations successful
```

This is the migration file which I have in the same path as `App.vue`. I also tried putting it in a separate folder and trying to glob it but no luck.

```js
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";

export class UserCreate1626771964722 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE "user" (
                "id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                "firstName" varchar NOT NULL,
                "age" integer NOT NULL
            )
        `);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`
            DROP TABLE "user"
        `);
    }

}
```

I don't have any other settings anywhere else and I am not sure why the migration (or entity) are not getting registered. Here is the full `console.log` of the `connection` object:

```json
{
    "migrations": [],
    "subscribers": [],
    "entityMetadatas": [],
    "name": "default",
    "options": {
        "type": "capacitor",
        "driver": {
            "sqlite": {},
            "_connectionDict": {}
        },
        "database": "mydrivetime",
        "synchronize": false,
        "migrationsRun": false,
        "logging": true,
        "entities": [
            "User"
        ],
        "migrations": [
            "1626771964722-UserCreate"
        ]
    },
    "logger": {
        "options": true
    },
    "driver": {
        "isReplicated": false,
        "treeSupport": true,
        "supportedDataTypes": [
            "int",
            "integer",
            "tinyint",
            "smallint",
            "mediumint",
            "bigint",
            "unsigned big int",
            "int2",
            "int8",
            "integer",
            "character",
            "varchar",
            "varying character",
            "nchar",
            "native character",
            "nvarchar",
            "text",
            "clob",
            "text",
            "blob",
            "real",
            "double",
            "double precision",
            "float",
            "real",
            "numeric",
            "decimal",
            "boolean",
            "date",
            "time",
            "datetime"
        ],
        "withLengthColumnTypes": [
            "character",
            "varchar",
            "varying character",
            "nchar",
            "native character",
            "nvarchar",
            "text",
            "blob",
            "clob"
        ],
        "spatialTypes": [],
        "withPrecisionColumnTypes": [
            "real",
            "double",
            "double precision",
            "float",
            "real",
            "numeric",
            "decimal",
            "date",
            "time",
            "datetime"
        ],
        "withScaleColumnTypes": [
            "real",
            "double",
            "double precision",
            "float",
            "real",
            "numeric",
            "decimal"
        ],
        "mappedDataTypes": {
            "createDate": "datetime",
            "createDateDefault": "datetime('now')",
            "updateDate": "datetime",
            "updateDateDefault": "datetime('now')",
            "deleteDate": "datetime",
            "deleteDateNullable": true,
            "version": "integer",
            "treeLevel": "integer",
            "migrationId": "integer",
            "migrationName": "varchar",
            "migrationTimestamp": "bigint",
            "cacheId": "int",
            "cacheIdentifier": "varchar",
            "cacheTime": "bigint",
            "cacheDuration": "int",
            "cacheQuery": "text",
            "cacheResult": "text",
            "metadataType": "varchar",
            "metadataDatabase": "varchar",
            "metadataSchema": "varchar",
            "metadataTable": "varchar",
            "metadataName": "varchar",
            "metadataValue": "text"
        },
        "connection": "...",
        "options": "...",
        "database": "mydrivetime",
        "driver": "...",
        "sqlite": "...",
        "databaseConnection": {}
    },
    "manager": {
        "repositories": [],
        "plainObjectToEntityTransformer": {},
        "connection": "..."
    },
    "namingStrategy": {
        "nestedSetColumnNames": {
            "left": "nsleft",
            "right": "nsright"
        },
        "materializedPathColumnName": "mpath"
    },
    "relationLoader": {
        "connection": "..."
    },
    "relationIdLoader": {
        "connection": "..."
    },
    "isConnected": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a well known issue with the TypeORM entity/migrations not working when they are minified. The fix is add vue config to prevent the classnames from being minified as follows:

```js
//vue.config.js (in the root folder)
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.optimization.minimizer('terser').tap((args) => {
        // see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced
        // https://cli.vuejs.org/migrating-from-v3/#vue-cli-service
        //   => chainWebpack for a chain override example
        // https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options for terser options
        const terserOptions = args[0].terserOptions
        // Avoid to mangle entities (leads to query errors)
        terserOptions["keep_classnames"] = true
        terserOptions["keep_fnames"] = true
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(args[0], null, 2))
        return args
      })
    }
  },
  // ...rest of your vue.config.js...
}
```

For further info, please check [this github issue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/issues/149)

Answer (score 1):

After some struggle, I found the working way of migrations and things to avoid when adding migrations.

**1. Use class as migrations array input instead of classnames or folder path.**

if you use classname or path, it will change in production mode because classnames are minified and you will start facing the following error.

```
Error during Data Source initialization i: Te migration name is wrong. Migration class name should have a JavaScript timestamp appended.
```

**2. Define name property of MigrationInterface to name of class.**

MigrationInterface already have name property defined, all you need to do is set this name property to name of class (with timestamp) so it will remain after your code is minified or even if you rename your class to without timestamp. See sample below.

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table} from "typeorm"

export class CreateGradeDownloadStatusTable implements MigrationInterface {

    name = 'CreateGradeDownloadStatusTable1691033085995'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {}

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {}

}
```